# How does one merge a list, but maintain the previous lists order?

Tags: python, list, merge

I have this list once merged using the below gives me this output.

```
['description t2_HELP', 'description t2_1507', 'description t2_1189', 'description t2_5625', 'description None', 'description None', 'description None', 'description None', 'interface Gi3/0/13', 'interface Gi3/0/7', 'interface Gi1/0/11', 'interface Gi3/0/41']
```

I however want to maintain the order of that data when I merge it in. So example list set would look like this.

```
['interface Gi3/0/25','description None','description t2_2696','interface Gi1/0/29','description None','description t2_4148','interface Gi1/0/31','description None','description t2_4212','interface Gi2/0/31','description None','description t2_4271']
```

Here is how i'm merging the lists,

```py
joinlist = data1 + data2 + data3
```

the lists look something like this

```
data1 = ['interface Gi3/0/25','interface Gi1/0/29','interface Gi1/0/31','interface Gi2/0/31']
data2 = ['description None','description None','description None','description None']
data3 = ['description t2_2696','description t2_4148','description t2_4212','description t2_4271']
```

Comment: Can we assume all lists always have the same size?

Comment: @Paul is right. The output lists aren't correct for the given input lists

Comment: Maybe use simpler example with lists like `['a', 'b', ...]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The other suggestions are fine if you have equal length `list`s (`zip`) or don't mind filler values in the result (`zip_longest`).

But logically what you're asking for here is a round robining of inputs, not a zipping. By flattening, you lose the paired-up aspect of `zip`, and can get bitten by it for uneven length inputs.

A more general solution to this problem is available with [the `itertools` module's `roundrobin` recipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes) (click the link for code, I'm just including usage here):

```
joinlist = list(roundrobin(data1, data2, data3))
```

That takes an element from each of the inputs in order; if one input is shorter than the others, it is omitted from later rounds without injecting garbage filler values or losing values from the longer input(s).

Answer (score 1):

Use built-in `zip` if you are okay with any longer list get truncated:

```
joinlist = []
for d in zip(data1,data2,data3):
    joinlist.extend(d)
```

Output:

```
['interface Gi3/0/25',
 'description None',
 'description t2_2696',
 'interface Gi1/0/29',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4148',
 'interface Gi1/0/31',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4212',
 'interface Gi2/0/31',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4271']
```

If you want to avoid the truncate, use `itertools.zip_longest`:

```
data2.append('test_me') # For testing purpose
joinlist = []
for d in zip_longest(data1,data2,data3):
    joinlist.extend(d)
```

Output:

```
['interface Gi3/0/25',
 'description None',
 'description t2_2696',
 'interface Gi1/0/29',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4148',
 'interface Gi1/0/31',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4212',
 'interface Gi2/0/31',
 'description None',
 'description t2_4271',
 None,
 'a',
 None]
```

Note: `None` at the end of the `joinlist` is because the `zip_longest`, by default, zips shorter iterable(s) with `None`. You can set any default value using `fillvalue` of `zip_longest`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of list comprehensions and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> [i for t in zip(data1, data2, data3) for i in t]
['interface Gi3/0/25', 'description None', 'description t2_2696', 'interface Gi1/0/29', 'description None', 'description t2_4148', 'interface Gi1/0/31', 'description None', 'description t2_4212', 'interface Gi2/0/31', 'description None', 'description t2_4271']
```

Comment: Note: `itertools`'s `chain.from_iterable` exists to optimize use cases like this (and enables some CPython `zip` optimizations a `list` comprehension can't use): `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(data1, data2, data3)))`.